# function is not being called

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to create a ghost like in pacman (which is an image) which will appear at random positions. Here is my code

```
function ghost(){
        while (true){

        e1.style.top = Math.round(Math.random() * document.body.scrollHeight) + 'px';
        document.body.appendChild(e1);

        }

        }
<body  onload="gameLoop();" onkeydown="" onkeyup="moveSelection(event)"  onload="ghost();">
```

I want it to run infintely side by side.

Comment: Beware, you have two `onload` on your `<body>` it should be like this: `onload="gameLoop();ghost();"`

Comment: You cannot write a game loop like that in javascript. Javascript is single threaded so your loop is going to keep iterating and not give time for the UI to update,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot code an infinite loop like this in Javascript because it will just run forever, blocking the browser from doing anything else and thus effectively "hanging" the browser until the browser will eventually abort the script.  The main Javascript execution in a browser is single threaded and thus if you loop forever like this, then nothing else can ever run.

Instead, you can use a `setInterval()` timer to update the position over time.  If you can describe in words exactly what you're trying to accomplish, we could likely help more specifically with recommended code.

In addition, you can only have one `onload` attribute on the body tag so you can either call both functions from one attribute or create a new function that calls multiple things and refer to that new function in the `onload` attribute.

Here's a plain use of `setInterval()`:

```
// something must set the e1 variable first
document.body.appendChild(e1);         
setInterval(function() {
    e1.style.top = Math.round(Math.random() * document.body.scrollHeight) + 'px';
}, 5000);
```

Note, per your code, this will cause the image to just jump around on the screen into random up/down positions every so often.